# How to work using multiple Rnw files?

Tags: r, rstudio, sweave

I have one Rnw file called name "main.Rnw" and it includes this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float} 
\title{Something}
\author{John Smith}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=1.15\textwidth}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\SweaveInput{reports/Child.Rnw}
\end{document}
```

In the file "Child.Rnw" I have:

```
% !Rnw root = Main.Rnw
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{float} 
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\section{section}
 Something something
\end{document}
```

Now it gives error:

```
  Error in SweaveReadFile(c(ifile, file), syntax, encoding = encoding) : 
  no Sweave file with name ‘./reports/Child.Rnw’ found
  Calls: <Anonymous> -> SweaveReadFile -> SweaveReadFile
  Execution halted
```

If I change the code and take away reports from command `\SweaveInput{reports/Child.Rnw}` (so. code is `\SweaveInput{Child.Rnw}` ) it gives error:

```
Writing to file Main.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
 Error in seq.default(from = which + 1L, length.out = length(linesout) -  : 
 'from' must be of length 1
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> seq -> seq.default
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In 1L:which : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
2: In seq.default(from = which + 1L, length.out = length(linesout) -  :
first element used of 'length.out' argument
Execution halted
```

What I do wrong?
I use R Studio.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems why your code doesn't work is because you are defining your document twice `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` are in your `Main.Rnw` and in `Child.Rnw`.

Your Child file `\SweaveInput{Child.Rnw}` should look like this:

```
% !Rnw root = main.Rnw
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\section{section}
 Something something
```

Try using this file and compile PDF.

I get PDF file of 3 pages

First is title, second content and third section.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. this helps.

Comment: Another problem when Child.Rnw was in the reports subdir:  it should have said `% !Rnw root = ../main.Rnw`, not `% !Rnw root = main.Rnw`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Sweave but the following should will with `knitr`.

You do not have to specify new document specification for Child.Rnw if they are supposed to be same, as default behaviour is to inherit attributes of the parent.

**Sweave to knitr**

```
#Convert Sweave specific options to knitr compatible version
#this will generate a new file named Parent-knitr.Rnw
library("knitr")
Sweave2knitr("Parent.Rnw")
```

**File Paths:**

For testing, let us assume following hypothetical directory structure

`D:/project/Parent.Rnw`

`D:/project/reports/Child.Rnw`

If Child.Rnw file is present in the same location as Parent.Rnw location
    the following should work

`\Sexpr{knit_child('Child.RnW')}`

If present at different location you need to specify full path of Child.Rnw and both 
    absolute and relative paths should work

absolute path e.g "D:/project/reports/Child.Rnw"

relative path e.g "../reports/Child.Rnw"

`.` implies current directory and  `..` implies moving one level up from working directory and working directory 
    is set to directory of Parent.Rnw as default by knitr.
    See ?knit_child for more documentation

**Parent.Rnw:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float} 
\title{Testing Parent Child Processing with knitr}
\author{John Smith}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=1.15\textwidth}
\begin{document}

<<include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(
concordance=TRUE
)
@

\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
%\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\tableofcontents
%\newpage
%\SweaveInput{reports/Child.Rnw}



\Sexpr{knit_child('./reports/Child.RnW')}
\end{document}
```

**Child.Rnw:**

```
\textbf{Testing Child.Rnw Processing:}

<<testChild>>=

data(mtcars)
plot(hclust(dist(mtcars)))


@
```

**PDF Conversion:**

```
knit2pdf("Parent-knitr.Rnw")
```

**Output:**

[image]